# Mejor manera de declara funciones en c++

Tags: c++, funciones, optimización, programación-funcional, lógica

¿Alguien me puede decir cuál es la mejor manera en términos de optimización para declarar funciones en C++?

He visto que hay 2 maneras, la primera es declararla por encima del `main` y luego definirla debajo del `main`, y la segunda es declararla y definirla por encima del `main` de una vez.

Pregunto porque si es exactamente lo mismo no entendería porque la primera opción es usada a menos que sea por algo de optimización.

```
#include<iostream>

int hola();

int main(){
   return 0;
}

int hola(){
   return 4;
}
```

o

```
#include<iostream>

int hola(){
   return 5;
}

int main(){
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esto es por mera estética, no cambia nada en optimización, pero es una buena pactica definirlas primero y después desarrollarlas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Alguien me puede decir cuál es la mejor manera en términos de optimización para declarar funciones en C++?

Si tu prioridad es la optimización, la mejor manera de declarar funciones es con `constexpr` o `consteval`.

Una función `constexpr` será reemplazada por el resultado de su llamada al compilar si se le facilitan datos conocidos en tiempo de compilación. Es decir: una función `constexpr` puede no generar código ni consumir tiempo de ejecución.

Una función `consteval`  será reemplazada por el resultado de su llamada al compilar si se le facilitan datos conocidos en tiempo de compilación, en caso contrario generará un error de compilación.

```
#include<iostream>

constexpr int hola(int don_pepito){
   return 5 + don_pepito;
}

consteval int adios(int don_jose){
   return 5 + don_jose;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   std::cout
       << hola(1)      // No genera código, se reemplaza por un 6.
       << hola(argc)   // Genera código y se ejecutará.
       << adios(2)     // No genera código, se reemplaza por un 7.
       << adios(argc); // Error de compilación.

   return 0;
}
```

> He visto que hay 2 maneras, la primera es declararla por encima del `main` y luego definirla debajo del `main`, y la segunda es declararla y definirla por encima del `main` de una vez.
>
> Pregunto porque si es exactamente lo mismo no entendería porque la primera opción es usada a menos que sea por algo de optimización.

El caso de separar la declaración y la definición **no tiene nada que ver con optimización**. Se suele hacer esa separación por claridad (separando las declaraciones en archivos de cabecera y las definiciones en archivos de código) o por necesidad.

Imagina un caso en que dos funciones sean mutuamente dependientes:

```
void f1(int v)
{
    if (v < 10)
        f2(v + 1); // ¡Error! ¿Qué es 'f2'?
}

void f2(int v)
{
    if (v > 1)
        f1(v + 1);
}
```

Tal y como están redactadas las funciones, el programa no compilaría. Al compilar `f1` la función `f2` no existe, lo cuál provoca un error de compilación. Pero si separas la definición y declaración el problema desaparece:

```
void f1(int);
void f2(int);

void f1(int v)
{
    if (v < 10)
        f2(v + 1); // Correcto, ya se que 'f2' es una función que recibe un entero.
}

void f2(int v)
{
    if (v > 1)
        f1(v + 1);
}
```